# ggplot2 geom_point with shape = 1 does not display circles

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

I tried to recreate a plot from "the Economist" which worked out quiet great. The only thing that didn't work is the fact that although I used the following code, the data points are not circles.

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x=CPI, y=HDI, color = Region)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 1) + 
  theme_economist_white()
```

[image]

I hope somebody here can help me out.

Comment: I guess you need `shape = 21`

Comment: `shape = 1` *should* give you hollow circles. What did you get?

Comment: ,,,,looks like circles to me. Do an image search for "R pch" and choose whichever you want!

Comment: I do get hollow circles, but Kind of swirly. I tried shape = 21, funny enough it seems like it doesn't make any difference, all the other ones Change like Always, but These two are the same...